# Position of preposition in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

> Set 1
> a. This is the topic that I will write on. 
> b) This is the topic I will write on.
> c) This is the topic which I will write on.
> d) This is the topic on which I will write.

> Set 2
> a. I know the man that you were talking to. 
> b. I know the man you were talking to. 
> c. I know the man whom you were talking to. 
> d. I know the man to whom you were talking.

I think that the sentences *a, b and c* in both the above sets  are correct. Are the last ones(d in both sets) also grammatical? I mean, can the preposition be placed before the relative pronoun?

Comment: You're looking at the difference between [prepositional stranding and pied-piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping#Preposition_stranding).  This isn't so much a question of grammar as it is a question of style and register.

Answer (score 0):

All eight sentences are fine. They vary in how formal they are - d. is much more formal in both cases.